# jQuery hover animation on only one element out of similar others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to Js and jQuery, and I managed to set up a width change animation on a div when I hover on an other. But when I put 3 similar groups of divs, a hover on one, triggers the action on all the others. I tried to put some "this" and "next()"  but it just stopped working altogether. Can you enlighten me please. Thank you

Here is the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/HiD3f/LmbaL1qo/2/

```
<html>
   <div class="mapHideBtn collapsed"></div>
   <div class="searchBlock hidden"></div>

   <div class="mapHideBtn collapsed"></div>
   <div class="searchBlock hidden"></div>

   <div class="mapHideBtn collapsed"></div>
   <div class="searchBlock hidden"></div>
</html>

<style>
  .searchBlock {
     display : inline-block;
     height: 50px;
     background : red;  
  }
  .hidden {
     width: 0; 
     transition : width 0.4s ease-in
  }
  .shown {
     width: 300px;
     transition : width 0.4s ease-in
  }
  .mapHideBtn {
     display : inline-block;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     background : green;
  }
</style>

<script>
  $('.mapHideBtn').hover(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed")) {
    $('.searchBlock').removeClass("hidden").addClass("shown");
    $('.mapHideBtn').removeClass("collapsed").addClass("expanded");
  } 

  else {
   $('.searchBlock').removeClass("shown").addClass("hidden");
   $('.mapHideBtn').removeClass("expanded").addClass("collapsed");
  };
});
```

Comment: how's this: https://jsfiddle.net/LmbaL1qo/4/?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `$(this).next()` and `toggleClass()` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/LmbaL1qo/3/)

```js
$('.mapHideBtn').hover(function(){
  $(this).next().toggleClass('shown');
});
```

Update: If you want red bar to stay open when you hover over it, you can use this pure CSS approach [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/LmbaL1qo/7/) or place `.searchBlock` inside `.mapHideBtn` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/LmbaL1qo/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your jQuery selectors to `$(this)` and `$(this).next()`.

What you are experiencing is a type of loop that finds ALL of the selectors you marked and runs the rules on them.

Here's a fixed fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/LmbaL1qo/5/

And here is the code:

```
$('.mapHideBtn').hover(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed")) {
    $(this).next().removeClass("hidden").addClass("shown");
    $(this).removeClass("collapsed").addClass("expanded");
  } else {
    $(this).next.removeClass("shown").addClass("hidden");
    $(this).removeClass("expanded").addClass("collapsed");
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple:

```
<script>
    $('.mapHideBtn').hover(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed")) {
        $(this).next().removeClass("hidden").addClass("shown");
        $('.mapHideBtn').removeClass("collapsed").addClass("expanded");
    } 

    else {
        $('.searchBlock').removeClass("shown").addClass("hidden");
        $('.mapHideBtn').removeClass("expanded").addClass("collapsed");
    }
});
</script>
```